# Reading a PDF File using google cloud vision

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am currently trying to read a pdf using the google cloud vision API. In my current code I have a path that leads to a storage bucket in my google cloud storage. Instead I want my program to be able to read files from my local storage. What should I change in my code to get this to work? I have attached my code below.

[Code part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51UE9.png)

[Code Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTWSh.png)

Comment: Please post your code in text format so it can be easily reproduced by community members.

Answer (score 4):

Based from your code you are using `async_batch_annotate_files()` to process the PDF files. It is not possible to process local PDF files using this method. `async_batch_annotate_files()` is limited to reading PDF files from Google Cloud Storage since this method is intended to process huge PDF files as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf#limitations).

> The Vision API accepts PDF/TIFF files up to 2000 pages.
>
> Currently PDF/TIFF (async_batch_annotate_files) document detection **is only available for files stored in Cloud Storage buckets**. Response JSON files are similarly saved to a Cloud Storage bucket.

---

But if you really want to read PDF files locally, it is possible by using `batch_annotate_files()` but this has its limitation. It is only capable to **process PDF files up to 5 pages**. See [Small batch file annotation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/file-small-batch) for more details. Here is the sample code from the documentation:

```
import io

from google.cloud import vision_v1


def sample_batch_annotate_files(file_path="local_path/to/your/document.pdf"):
    """Perform batch file annotation. Limited to PDF files up to 5 pages"""
    client = vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    # Supported mime_type: application/pdf, image/tiff, image/gif
    mime_type = "application/pdf"
    with io.open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        content = f.read()
    input_config = {"mime_type": mime_type, "content": content}
    features = [{"type_": vision_v1.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION}]

    # The service can process up to 5 pages per document file. Here we specify
    # the first, second, and last page of the document to be processed.
    pages = [1, 2, -1]
    requests = [{"input_config": input_config, "features": features, "pages": pages}]

    response = client.batch_annotate_files(requests=requests)
    for image_response in response.responses[0].responses:
        print(u"Full text: {}".format(image_response.full_text_annotation.text))
        for page in image_response.full_text_annotation.pages:
            for block in page.blocks:
                print(u"\nBlock confidence: {}".format(block.confidence))
                for par in block.paragraphs:
                    print(u"\tParagraph confidence: {}".format(par.confidence))
                    for word in par.words:
                        print(u"\t\tWord confidence: {}".format(word.confidence))
                        for symbol in word.symbols:
                            print(
                                u"\t\t\tSymbol: {}, (confidence: {})".format(
                                    symbol.text, symbol.confidence
                                )
                            )
```